# SVG in Android Studio for every screen resolution

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, drawable

There is something I don't really understand in android when it comes to SVG files.
I've been working lately with SVG files, what I usually do is create a vector asset (XML layout file) in the drawable directory from the original SVG file. By doing this, I can easily display vector graphics, but the same file doesn't render correctly in all screens, unless I change its dimensions when creating the vector asset from the default 24dp by 24dp to its original size. This makes me wonder, do I have to create one vector asset with different size for each screen or what?, what would be the best solution?

Tha

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to alter the VectorDrawable. Just specify a width and a height in the ImageView and, if necessary, an appropriate `scaleType`.